# Disable copy & paste options in EditText longClick not working

Tags: android

Disable copy & paste options in EditText longClick not working. What I have done is

```
  password.setLongClickable(false);
    password.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override this method and add mode.finish(), to stop default options for cut, copy, past, etc.

```
  @Override
  public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {     
    super.onSupportActionModeStarted(mode);
    mode.finish();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using below code

```
  mEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Create the custom class for the Edittext and handle its on touch event as below, its works:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mDisableCursorHandle) {
        // Hack to prevent keyboard and insertion handle from showing.
        cancelLongPress();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I did same as like what you pasted here(Plz look into above code).Copy and paste disabling but after click on blue cursor its visibling with COPY and CLIPBOARD options.

Comment: check with custom EditText with touchevent handling mention above, and let me know this issue is resolved or not

Comment: bhavesh N : would you provide complete code please. so that i can test .Thanks.